# Store Switcher redirect default store

Tags: magento2.2, redirect

I am having a problem with store switcher. I created two stores:

1. English store and
2. Arabic store

When I switch the store English into Arabic, it redirects me to default English store. Here is my URL http://www.hit-counts.com/vinca/default/brands.html.

It's working properly throughout the website except for shop pages/catalog pages.

I am using Magento Version 2.2

Comment: Can you please upload your code ?

Comment: Please share your email address i will give you access.

Comment: do you have enabled  Add Store Code to Urls from admin configuration ?

Comment: you can check this from store->configuration->General->web->url options section

Comment: if this option is enabled then store switcher not working properly in magento 2.2

Comment: Yes i enabled that url options section because if i disable this url option the home page encounter some errors while switching from one store to another store
the errors are :
1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException): Requested store is not found

Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException): Requested store is not found
#0 /home/hosthitc/public_html/vinca/vendor/magento/module-store/Model/StoreManager.php(168): Magento\Store\Model\StoreRepository->get('arabic?___store...')

Comment: yes this is issue in magento 2.2 please check this link https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/10908

Comment: also check this link :- https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/2786

Comment: which version are  you using of magento ?

Comment: In Magento 2.2.2  this are resolved

Comment: I am using Magento 2.2. Now what should i do can you please guide me?

Comment: this issue solved in magento 2.2.2 version if you want then you can upgrade to magento 2.2.2